# Tcp checksum oF Retransmission packet SDN network (openflow protocol)

Tags: tcp, wireshark, checksum, mininet, openflow

I have created a SDN network in the  mininet and i started to push a tcp flow between 2 hosts  by using iperf command .  I use wireshark for some analysis. I found that when the packet is retransmitted for any reason, the checksum of the retransmitted packet is totally different from the original one that has been lost.
I think they should be the same . Could any one has any interpretation for that ?

Comment: Maybe you could share a small capture file on any easily accessible file sharing service, dropbox, pastebin, google drive, cloudshark, etc?

Comment: Which checksum is changing? The IP checksum or TCP checksum?